# azure web service: webconfig subdomain files rewrite

Tags: iis, web-config

Hi I have a react website with sbdomain app.mywebsite.com and I have redirected to a folder with the following rewrite in webconfig

```
        <rule name="appRedirect"  stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(app\.)(.*)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
```

The app works fine until I refresh the website with the url updated.

For eg. I can access app.mywebsite.com and the app will take me to app.mywebsite.com/mylink dynamically. The problem is I cannnot access the website when I access app.mywebsite.com/mylink directly.

I tried adding 
            `<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />`
as well but it wont work as the whole subdomain is redirected

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding a webconfig file in the app directory and rewriting 404 pages to index.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
       <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File" >
         <remove statusCode="404" />
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="404" 
            path="index.html" />
         <error statusCode="500" 
            path="500.html" />
       </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```